# how can i execute function when i press in (ok) in date piker? react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to execute manage function after i choose the date from date piker and press ok

how can i do that ?? 
here is my code

```
 <DatePicker

                    date={this.state.date}
                    mode="date"
                    placeholder="date"
                    format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                    minDate={todayDate}
                    confirmBtnText="OK"
                    cancelBtnText="Cancel"


                />
```

and here is my function that i want to execute it

```
    manage = () => {

    const office_id=this.state.office_id;
    const date=this.state.date;
    const duration =this.state.duration;

 const  url2='http://myIP/api/timeApi';
    axios.post(url2,{duration,office_id,date})
    .then(resp =>alert('done'))
    .catch(err => alert(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using following package:
https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker
which have exposed `onDateChange` event handler. So this:

```
<DatePicker
    date={this.state.date}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="date"
    format="DD/MM/YYYY"
    minDate={todayDate}
    confirmBtnText="OK"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    onDateChange={this.manage.bind(this)} // <----
/>
```

should do the job.